# Moment-generating function

Tags: statistics, moment-generating-functions

Let X~Exponential(1).

I know that the moment-generating function of an exponential distribution is defined as $(1-t\lambda)^{-1}$. And hence $E[e^{tx}]=(1-t)^{-1}$.

But what is $E[Xe^{tx}]$? Would that be the first moment of the moment-generating function?

Comment: I think writing the integral tells all. It may appear like a first moment.

Comment: Either compute the relevant integral by any mean you like, or use the shortcut $$E(Xe^{tX})=\frac{d}{dt}E(e^{tX})$$ (FYI, the phrase "the first moment of the moment-generating function" makes no sense.)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your parameter $\lambda$ is taken to be the expected value of $X$, $X$ has probability density
$$f_{X} (x) = \frac{1}{\lambda} \exp\left(-\frac{x}{\lambda}\right).$$
So the expected value $E\left[Xe^{tX}\right]$ is just the integral
$$\frac{1}{\lambda} \int_{0}^{\infty} x e^{tx} e^{-x/\lambda} \ dx$$
which reduces to some integration by parts. Assuming that $t < 1/\lambda$,
$$E\left[Xe^{tX}\right] = \lim_{y \to \infty} - \frac{1}{1 - \lambda t} ye^{-( 1/\lambda - t)y} + \frac{1}{1 - \lambda t}\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{(t - 1/\lambda)x} \ dx$$
$$= \frac{\lambda}{(1 - \lambda t)^2}.$$

---

Alternatively,
$$E\left[X e^{tX} \right] = E[X] + t E[X^2] + \frac{1}{2!} t^2 E[X^3] + \dots$$
$$= \frac{d}{dt} \left(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n!} t^{n} E[X^n]\right)$$
$$= M_{X}'(t),$$
where $M_{X} (t)$ is your MGF.